# Regex replace doesn't replace the matched numbers

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace attribute values using a regex check but when I try to replace the numbers it doesn't work. When I check the console I can see that the numbers are getting changed correctly:

```
["5, 6"] //This is what I get after the initial matching
[4, 5] //This is the result after I've done the converting and subtracting
```

In my `for loop` I convert the items in the array to integers first and then I subtract each by 1.

```
button.on('click', function() {

    var btnParent = $(this).parent().parent();
        btnParent.fadeOut(400, function() {
            btnParent.remove();
        });

    btnParent.nextAll('li').find('input, label').each(function () {

        var self = $(this);

        $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
            var attribValue = attrib.value;
            var attribName = attrib.name;
            var intRegex = /\d+/g;
            var originalNum = attribValue.match(intRegex);
            var newNum = originalNum;
            var newValue;

            if (newNum != null) {
                for (j = 0; j < newNum.length; j++) {

                    parseInt(newNum[j]);
                    newNum[j]--;
                    newValue = attribValue.replace(originalNum[j], newNum[j]); //This doesn't work
                }
            }

            self.attr('' + attribName, newValue);
        });
    });
```

Console output:

```
The original value is: text5 (type = string) 
The original num is: 5 (type = object)
The new num is: 4 (type = number)
The new value is: text5 (type = string)
```

Despite everything working I can't get it to replace any numbers, I suspect that it might have something to do with types, that it can't change the original number when it's an object or a string and the new num is a number or something like that. I've tried to change it so that they correspond but either I get NaN or I get no difference in output. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're just using `attrib.name` and `attrib.value` and not checking if its `name` attribute or not. Better approach would be to do the following

```
$('[name]').each(function() {
   $(this).attr("name", reduceBy1);
   $(this).attr("id", reduceBy1); 
});
function reduceBy1(_, n){
   return n.replace(/\d+/g, function(m){ return --m });
}
```

Comment: But it's not just "name" attribute I'm changing, I used it just as an example. Thing is without the loop it works when changing 1 number but when I have for example question2choice1 it only changed the 1 after choice and not the number after question. That's why I'm using a loop. Your solution wouldn't do anything to help this I think.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz what other attributes do you want to change?

Comment: The ones I need right now are: name, id, for. But I still don't understand how to change your function so that it works with what I've already done.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you can just use my code now, appending attributes you want to change

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function" for the return line in reduceBy1. Should there be something in between the regex and function start? I tried using a comma but didn't work either

Comment: It's still giving me the same error for: return n.replace(/\d+/g function(m){ return --m }); Before the it's the function(m) that gives the error

Comment: @Chrillewoodz ah! Yes. Missed a comma after regex. Now it should work

Comment: "n" is undefined since nothing gets passed into the reduceBy1 function, but when I send something into it, it can't run "replace" because "undefined is not a function". Here's what I tried to do to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/t5uzk17u/

Comment: @Chrillewoodz ah! Really do you think it would work? There is no html.

Comment: I didn't include 500 lines of code that creates the HTML, lol. There is HTML but I just wanted to show how I modified your solution.

Comment: Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5uzk17u/3/ line 238, are you able to make your function work if you change the fiddle?